# If $f_n(x)$ converges to $0$ point-wise on $[0,1]$. Does $\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)dx$ coverges to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Suppose $(f_{n})_{n\in \mathbb {N} }$ is a sequence of continuous functions on the closed interval $[0,1]$ converging to $0$ point-wise. Then the integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx$$

converges to $0$.

I have to check that the whether the above statement is TRUE or FALSE.

My attempt:

If the sequence $(f_{n})_{n\in \mathbb {N} }$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ with limit $0$. Then for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ and $x\in [0,1]$

$$|f_{n}(x)|<\epsilon.$$

This implies
$$\Big{|} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx \Big{|} \leq  \int_{0}^{1} |f_n(x)| dx <\epsilon$$
for all $n \geq N$. Thus $\int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx$ converges to 0.

The problem with the point-wise convergence is there is no guarantee that such a $N$ would exist which works for all $x \in [0,1]$.

I think the statement seems to be true nonetheless. It would be helpful if some could help me prove it or provide me with a counter example.

Comment: **Fatou's Lemma** is probably in your textbook.  It shows an inequality here.  And I expect there is also an example showing where strict equality fails.

Comment: For example: [Find a sequence of R-integrable functions whose pointwise limit is R-integrable but the limit of $\int (f_n)$ does not equal to $\int f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1171454) or [$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int^1_0 f_n(x)dx=0$ , is $f_n$ pointwise convergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/603742)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f_n$ be a broken line joining $(0,0), \left(\frac{1}{2n},n\right), \left(\frac{1}{n},0\right)$ and $(1,0)$. Then $f_n\to 0$ pointwise, while all the integrals are $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take as a counterexample the function $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\\
                                             2n^2x & x \in[0,\frac{1}{2n}]\\
                                             -2n^2(x-\frac{1}{n}) & x \in [\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}]\\
                                              0 & x \in [\frac{1}{n},1]\\
                                                \end{cases}$

Comment: $f_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ at $0$.

Comment: This isn't continuous but one only need to make a slight fix to make it continuous.

Comment: @d.k.o o the sequence converges to zero pointwise.

Comment: $f_n=n$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams i missed the continuous assumption..i will fix it or provide another counterexample.

Comment: @d.k.o. if $x=0$ then we have the problem..i changed the function a little

Answer (score 0):

False.

Example: $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{e^{nx^2}},x\in [0,1].$