Sequence of functions in $C^\infty ([0, 1])$ which satisfy $\int_0^1|f_i(t)|dt = 1$ and converge pointwise to 0
I think taking bump functions supported in neighborhoods of $1/n$ should work, but I wonder if there's a more explicit construction.
Here's my answer so far:

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and real number $\alpha_n$ there exists a $C^\infty$ bump function with value $\alpha_n$ in a neighbourhood of $1/n$ and with support in $\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$. By intermediate value theorem we can choose $\alpha_n$ such that its integral is exactly 1. The sequence of these functions satisfies the required contitions.


See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3459644/42969

Nice! Looks like $f_n(x)=\frac{2nx}{e^{nx^2}}$ is almost what I'm looking for: it is $C^\infty$ and the integral converges to 1, though the integral isn't exactly 1
